# Get Url Vue js (Router)

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, router, quasar

i am developing an app in vue js with quasar and i would like to get current url in the index.js of Router folder but i do not know how. the problem is we can not access to window and ever $router to get url.
can anybody help me?

Comment: why can't you access the window or $router?  what do you need the current url for?

Comment: this file loads before route, thats why i cant access them.
we have got some subdomain and i would not like to access some of them to some routes. thats why i am gonna use navigation guards in this respect and for that i need to get the url and chek subdomain.
have you got any idea?

Comment: So you want to use the route in the navigation guard?  It's hard to tell what you're doing without showing us any code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If a file loads before route you can still access all the functions with beforeEach

```
router.beforeEach(function(to,from,next){
    console.log(to,from);

 )
}
```

I did not understand your problems correctly. from is the current route location perhaps you can save it in a const variable.